# Media queries dentro do nesting - Sass

Tags: css, react, sass

Tenho uma dúvida, estou criando uma aplicação em React, logo, estou usando SASS.

Mas a minha dúvida é referente ao SASS, se é uma boa prática eu inserir media querie dentro do meu bloco de css.

Exemplo que eu estou fazendo agora, e estou com dúvidas se é uma boa prática ou não.
[image: Media queries dentro do nesting]
Eu usei isto, para evitar de abrir um novo media queries por fora do escopo do meu nesting...

A dúvida é

Este modo é uma má prática? Porquê?

Answer (score 0):

SCSS não é executado, SCSS/SASS é convertido em CSS, e sim, escrever um media-query dentro do SCSS será convertido no CSS de forma correta, a linguagem SCSS não é uma linguagem de uso ("executável") e sim para facilitar o desenvolvimento e repetições de código e no final é convertido para CSS, algo como:

```
ul#menu
{
  li {
    text-align: left;

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px)
    {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

É convertido em:

```
ul#menu li {
  text-align: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ul#menu li {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Inclusive na própria DOC oficial tem exemplos: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media

---

Se tiver duvidas que algo irá ou não funcionar pode instalar o SCSS fora do React (React assim como o Ionic já possuem com o compilador SCSS internamente) ou usar uma ferramenta online:

- http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php